# add selectable blank field to php form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Ticket Edit table on my website and I have a row called 'Staff' in the table. I want to add a blank filed to this drop down row and anyone can select it as blank.

this is my php code of the row:

```
<tr><td>Staff</td><td><select name='call_staff'>
<?php $staff_name = $db->get_results("select user_id,user_name from site_users where user_level<>1 order by user_name;");

foreach ($staff_name as $staff )
{?>

<option value='<?php echo $staff->user_id;?>'<?php if($staff->user_id == $call_staff){echo ' selected';}?>><?php echo $staff->user_name;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select></td></tr>
```

when someone wants to select the staff , this only have the values that are already in database such as John or Kitty or else . but i want to add a field which is blank and selectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a extra option tag after your select tag

```
<tr><td>Staff</td><td><select name='call_staff'>
<option value="0"></option>
<?php $staff_name = $db->get_results("select user_id,user_name from site_users where user_level<>1 order by user_name;");

foreach ($staff_name as $staff )
{?>

<option value='<?php echo $staff->user_id;?>'<?php if($staff->user_id == $call_staff){echo ' selected';}?>><?php echo $staff->user_name;?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
<select name='call_staff'>
```

You can simply add the following simple html code:

```
<option value="none"></option>
```

- It's another select-able option
- It's blank **but** still has a value (for a possible later use in your php code)

Comment: i did this but after i update the ticket , it automatically select a staff row like Kitty or John.

Comment: I'll check the specs for that behavior, anyway you can add the `SELECTED` attribute, `<option value="none" SELECTED></option>`

Comment: it still not working , but i changed "none" to "0" and it worked for me